# Class attributes/methods without defining them Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am seeing the code shown below for the 1st time, which I have never learned or seen anywhere else before. I have only seen Class attributes or Instance attributes. How does this one below work? Can we just add any class attributes/methods like this way?

```
class Globals:
    pass

g = Globals()

g.tasks = []
g.diff_list = []
g.pdf_list = []
g.tstamp = None
g.terminated = False
g.num_task_retries = 4
```

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, this code is adding attributes to one instance of the class, not the class itself. But it would also be okay to do `Globals.foo = "bar"` to add an attribute to the class.

Comment: Yes, it is adding attributes to this particular instance `g` of `Globals` class. I have never seen this before.

Comment: There are valid reasons to do this... but not that many. Any instance variable used by a class's methods should be setup in `__init__` (or other methods). No method on this class should depend on any of these variables being there. However, some people like to add variables to class instances because they find attribute lookup it more cool than using a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify otherwise using `__slots__`, Python classes are basically just wrappers over dictionaries. They can be given arbitrary attributes at any time. To prevent this, you specify `__slots__` on the class, which limits the attributes that can be added, and has performance benefits as well:

```
class Globals:
    __slots__ = ["a"]

g = Globals()
g.a = 1  # Fine
g.b = 2  # AttributeError: 'Globals' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Comment: You can also write a `__setattr__` method that rejects some or all attribute assignments.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes. You won't get the performance benefits in that case though. It would be an option if you wanted to do something bizarre like dynamically accept/reject attributes.

Comment: But with `__slots__` you also loose the ability for instance methods to add any instance attributes that are not in a slot. I wouldn't hazard a guess about performance benefits either way without profiling. Slotted classes still have a `__setattr__`.

Comment: Thanks! I never know this dunder function before. Does it also work on adding arbitrary methods like this way?